# Java score points automatically increasing

Tags: java, loops, increment, auto-increment, text-based

I'm doing a school project. I am building a text based game on Java for PC.
The game I'm building is quite simple, you buy homes and you rent them out. So what I am asking is, how can i get the money to automatically increase per second ($1 per second) from each house and then automatically add it to their users bank account automatically. I have looked around and they say use a thread to pause the game for 1000(milliseconds) and then do counter++. But I have tried that, and for a text based game that pauses the game and makes the user wait. I want the user to continue interacting with other functionalities of the text based game whilst the money per second in his bank is increasing.

Comment: Instead of trying to do manual thread management, create a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) that runs once per second and does any required updating.

Comment: @Mazzoseven It will be good If you can show a sample program output.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that putting in a thread to sleep for 1000 ms is probably the best solution. The issue that you seem to have encountered when trying that solution is likely caused not using multithreading. The `Thread.sleep(1000);` command should be on a separate thread from the main thread that you are using for the user interface.

The following could be a possible way to implement the thread that modifies the bank balance:

```
 public class RevenueThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
       while(true){
          // add to bank balance
          MainClass.BankBalance += MainClass.PropertyCount * INCOME_PER_PROPERTY;

          // sleep for 1 second
          try{
             Thread.sleep(1000);
          }catch(Exception ex){
             System.err.println( ex.getMessage() );
          }

       }


    }


 }
```

*Modify that code to your needs with the proper variable names and whatnot.*

To integrate this with your code, you could add this to your main() function:

```
 Runnable rev = new RevenueThread();
 Thread revThread = new Thread(rev);
 revThread.start();`
```

**Note**: I apologize if my answer seems somewhat brief or if it contains any errors. I am typing this solution from my phone, so bear with me :P

---

**EDIT**: The following is an alternative (and perhaps more accurate) way to increment the bank balance every second:

```
public class RevenueThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        // Variable to keep track of payout timing:
        long lNextPayout = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000; // Current time + 1 second

        while(true){
            if(lNextPayout <= System.currentTimeMillis()){
                // At least 1000 milliseconds have passed since the last payout
                // Add money to the player's bank balance
                MainClass.BankBalance += MainClass.PropertyCount * INCOME_PER_PROPERTY;

                // Now set up the next payout time:
                lNextPayout += 1000;
            }

            // sleep for 50 milliseconds to prevent CPU exhaustion
            try{
                // Thread.sleep() can throw an InterruptedException.
                Thread.sleep(50);
            }catch(Exception ex){
                // If sleep() is interrupted, we should catch the exception
                // and print the error message to the standard error stream
                // (STDERR) by using System.err
                System.err.println( ex.getMessage() );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**What's different about this version and why is it better?** This version uses the system's current time to payout every 1000 milliseconds. Because `sleep()` can possibly throw an exception, this updated version prevents a user from being paid multiple times within 1 second just because `sleep()` threw an exception and did not sleep for the full second.

**How can this be used?** This can be used in the exact same way as the previous version. (I.e., just create a new `RevenueThread` object, then create a `Thread` object for it, and call `.start()` on that new thread.) Again, though, you should replace and rename variables as needed to fit into your project.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are doing a text based game and it is not indicated in your question whether this will be a multiplayer or single player game, if this is a single player game, I will not implement this simulation (game) in real time.

It is probably more suitable to implement a ***[discrete-time simulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_event_simulation)*** (which means you don't have to use threads). You can create each house as an object with a `currentTime` attribute. Every time a house is rented, update its `currentTime`. Whenever you need to check the bank account for the money received from renting. Check the elapsed renting time of each house and update your bank account accordingly.